# Using C#, how can I detect a broken link or tag?

Tags: c#, html, error-handling, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML file that it isn't syntactically correct, I'm parsing it with [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).

But if I have a link like

`<a href="http://google.com/!/!!!">Google</a>`

it's a problem, is there a possible way to detect broken links so that when an error is found (no page is available on that link) the application will store that link in a list and return it?

Same problem on tags, example:

```
<img hhh="jjj"/>
```

here the image tag is all wrong, this should be in the 'errors for repair' list too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop through `Document.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")` and check whether the `href` tag is bad.

Similarly, you can loop through `Document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")` and check for `src` attributes.

**EDIT**:

To check for bad attributes, you can maintain a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>` that maps tag names to valid attributes, then use LINQ to find missing attributes, like this:

```
from tag in Document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
let legalAttributes = allAttributes[tag.TagName]
from attribute in tag.Attributes
where !legalAttributes.Contains(attribute.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
select new { Tag = tag.OuterHtml, Attribute = attribute.Name }
```

Comment: I've done that :) but the question was how can i discover that the links are bad or not...

Comment: You can use the `WebClient` class to request the URL and see if you get an exception.

Comment: hmmm this is nice, but for the img tags for example? or body tags etc, is there a general way to repair them?

Comment: This solves only a little part of his problem. What do you do about the missing "src" in the image tag or the "hhh" that doesn't belong in there?

Comment: I mean, for my example with the 'img' tag, the 'hhh' attribute does not exists, how can I detect that this attribute does not exist for the img tag? Or for any tag...

Comment: You can get a list of valid attributes for each tag, then use LINQ to see if the tag has any bad attributes.

Comment: Can you update you answer with an example of this? Thank you very much

Comment: You can be fancier and have an inheritable AttributeValidator class that can check whether an attributes value is valid (eg, URL, number), and store that in a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, AttributeValidator>>` and validate every attribute.

Comment: This is what I was thinking right now, that in that list of attributes to be only valid entries.